# SetupApi : enable virtual network adapter using c++ setupApi

Tags: c++, windows, windows-api-code-pack, device-manager, setupapi

On windows, I am unable to find how to enable hotspot adapter i.e. virtual adapter through coding if it was disabled manually from 'Network Connections'.
I want to implement as we do from device manager and enable it by right click on network adapter.
One of the lib found from windows API which is setupApi but no idea how to use it.
Any suggestion for this?